# how to convert columns in to rows in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL that looks like this:

[image: THE TABLE THAT I HAVE]

I want to create the table in a way that looks like this :

[image: THE TABLE THAT I WANT TO CREATE]

i have tried to use PIVOT, but it does not give me what i want

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Price' attr, product_name, price val from mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Quantity' attr, product_name, quantity from mytable 
ORDER BY product_name, attr
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdZvpcphxoSjzQCdSFEo9K/1)**:

```
| attr     | product_name | val |
| -------- | ------------ | --- |
| Price    | Pr_1         | 30  |
| Quantity | Pr_1         | 123 |
| Price    | Pr_2         | 14  |
| Quantity | Pr_2         | 6   |
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but if i have a large number of columns is this an effective way ?

Comment: @rexhi: no, not in standard SQL. You would need to use dynamic SQL, which is much complex and seems to be beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `pivot`, which implies that you are using SQL Server or Oracle.  Those databases also support lateral joins.  In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
select t.product_name, v.col, v.val
from t cross apply
     (values ('Price', price),
             ('Quantity', quantity)
     ) v(col, val);
```

The syntax in Oracle is similar, but that database doesn't support `values()` so you have to use `select from dual`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Using CTE Method-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Product') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE Product;

CREATE TABLE Product
(
Product_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Price MONEY NOT NULL,
QUANTITY INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Product(Product_name,Price,QUANTITY)
VALUES
('Pr_1',30,123),('Pr_2',12,56);

-- SELECT Product_name,Price,QUANTITY FROM Product;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 'Price' AS [COL1],CAST(price AS INT) AS [COL3] FROM Product UNION ALL
SELECT 'Quantity',Quantity FROM Product
)
SELECT C.[Col1],p.Product_name,C.[Col3] FROM CTE C INNER JOIN Product P ON (C.[COL3]=P.PRICE OR C.[COL3]=P.QUANTITY);
```